# What is D/dalvikvm(831): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, logcat, android-logcat

I recently posted a question here: [Android app keeps crashing in emulator and Nexus 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499862/android-app-keeps-crashing-in-emulator-and-nexus-10/21501298). The response was that I should use Eclipse's LogCat feature to find the cause of why my app was crashing. When I ran the app through the emulator, this came up:

D/dalvikvm(831): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)

Does this have something to do with my app crashing? If so, how can I fix it?

Comment: did you find solution? if yes please post here

Comment: @Nicks Should be below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this log message does not represent any crashes. To understand more about this message, see the [Android documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/debugging-android-jni-with-checkjni.html).